# Why are enum ordinals not constant expressions?

Tags: java, enums

Take a look at this code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        switch (0) {
        case MyEnum.Test.ordinal():
            break;
        }
    }

    public static enum MyEnum {
        Test;
    }
}
```

This code will fail to compile with the error message:

> case expressions must be constant expressions.

This is because `MyEnum.Test.ordinal()` is not a constant. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()), the `ordinal()` method does this:

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

So why isn't the ordinal constant? Is an enum's position not constant? What's going on here?

Comment: Why would you need to switch on the ordinal, when you can switch on the value?

Comment: you have to switch on the enum itself not the ordinal() where you are basically calling a method

Comment: It's not a **constant**, because it's a **method call**.

Comment: @AndyTurner probably never, I just thought of this out of the blue.

Comment: Why the downvote? I feel like this is a legitimate question, especially from someone like me that doesn't know every single detail about Java (I've never reflected on that you obviously can't switch on method calls) and just happened to wonder why something that claims it's constant is actually not.

Comment: @Charanor it doesn't claim to be constant. "Constant" in "Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant" refers to the *enum value* (e.g. `MyEnum.Test`), not its ordinal. `MyEnum.Test` is a compile-time constant, per the spec, but anything returned by one of its instance methods isn't.

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite correct there: `MyEnum.Test` can be used in a `SwitchLabel` because of the production [`case EnumConstantName :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11), not because it's a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Charanor, if you read the Java Language Specification (JLS) anent the `switch` construct, you'll see that it accepts only enum constants or constant expressions for which "The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type". The term "constant expression" is defined in the JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28 From that information it's clear why you can't use `ordinal()` in a `switch`.

Comment: I would restrain from using the ordinal of an enum. If someone changes the order of the enumerated values, then your code will break. If you use the enum names, you do not have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum.ordinal()` is a function.  A function invocation can never be a compile time constant. (Not even close.)

The creators of the language could have perhaps chosen to introduce a special keyword instead of a function for obtaining the ordinal of an Enum, (It could be `Enum.ordinal` like `Object.class`) but I suppose they decided against it because

a) it unnecessarily complicates the language, and

b) it does not offer anything at all that you cannot trivially accomplish by other means.

c) from the documentation of `ordinal()`: "Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.".

In your example, you can try converting the `int` to an instance of your `enum`, and then `switch` by the actual instance.

Comment: The other point that you've not mentioned here is from the [Javadoc of `ordinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()): "Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.". You're simply not meant to use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The results of methods are never compile-time constants. `ordinal()` is in no way special, it's just like every other (instance) method.

You can find a list of expression types which can be compile-time constants [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).